# Both validation accuracy and validation loss increasing

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am training a long short term memory (LSTM) Recurrent Neural Network.

After certain epochs, both the validation loss and validation accuracy increases. Either one of them should decrease but that is not the case.

Note that the number of classes in 6.

Comment: though this might be off-topic on Stack Overflow (e.g. not a programming question) there is no question at all. could you please edit your post and make clear what you are asking ?

Comment: Yes, sometimes this will happen, [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/258166/good-accuracy-despite-high-loss-value/281651#281651) may be helpful.